# ExtJs put a tooltip to the horizontal scroll controls Tab Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I have a `tab panel` with some items inside them, when I add many elements the panel puts a horizontal movement controlers, how can i do to put a `tooltip` in this controls?

[image: Tab Panel]

This is the definition of my tab Panel:

```
        var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel',{
        id: 'tabTabla',
        items: [{
            title: 'list1',
            tooltip: 'list1',
            items:[tree]
        }, {
            title: 'list2',
            tooltip: 'list2',
            autoWidth : true,
            autoHeight : true,
            plain : true,
            defaults : {
                autoScroll : true,
                bodyPadding : 0
            },
            items: [{
                xtype : 'label',
                text : 'list description.',
            },
            gridV]
        },{
            title: 'list3',
            tooltip: 'list3',
            autoWidth : true,
            autoHeight : true,
            plain : true,
            defaults : {
                autoScroll : true,
                bodyPadding : 0
            },
            items: [
                    gridC
                    ]
        }]
    });

    var scrollers = Ext.select('.x-box-scroller-tab-bar').elements;
    Ext.each(scrollers, function(scroll, id) {
    scroll.title =  (id == 0 ? 'left click' : 'right click');
    });
```

In this tab Panel I add more panels:

```
    Ext.apply(this, {
        title: 'TITLE',
        constrain: true,
        header : {
            titlePosition : 2,
            titleAlign : 'center'
        },
        closable : false,
        x : 20,
        y : 270,
        layout : 'fit',
        animCollapse : true,
        collapsible : true,
        collapseDirection : Ext.Component.DIRECTION_LEFT,
        items: [tabPanel]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is not good solution, but you can use it until you find better solution. Fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/tng

```
var scrollers = Ext.select('.x-box-scroller-tab-bar');
Ext.each(scrollers, function(scroll, id) {
    scroll.set({
        "data-qtip": id == 0 ? 'left click' : 'right click'       
    });
});
```

Or

```
    var scrollers = Ext.select('.x-box-scroller-tab-bar').elements;
    Ext.each(scrollers, function(scroll, id) {
        scroll.title =  (id == 0 ? 'left click' : 'right click')       

    });
```

Comment: This code works on the fiddle, , I put your code in my own code, but I can't make it works on my app,what am I doing wrong?. I'm using ExtJs 5.1

Comment: 'Ext.select' finds dom elements by class. So, you should find your tab scroller's class. Inspect element on your browser> find class > then use Ext.select(scrollerclass).

Comment: Btw, if you are still unable to find class, it might help you to find elements : console.log(tabPanel.getTabBar().getEl().dom.children[0].children)

Comment: I inspected the dom of the element at this level: `tabPanel -> tabBar -> el -> dom -> children[0] -> children[0] -> classname` and I found this classname : `x-box-scroller x-box-scroller-left x-box-scroller-tab-bar x-box-scroller-tab-bar-default x-unselectable x-box-scroller-disabled` is this class name that I need?

Comment: Actually, classname is same with classname in my code. It is supposed to work. What comes when you put console.log(Ext.select('.x-box-scroller-tab-bar')) to your code?

Comment: If its 'null', you should put that code block to tab panel listeners.Try this:  listeners: { afterrender: function(tabpanel) { // my code block } }